# Pass route param to child component as input in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template

I have a parent component which gets an id value from a route parameter.  I want to pass this to a child component so I'm doing that via an `Input()` decorator on the child component.  However, I'm having trouble in getting the route param value through to the child.  If I hard-code a value and pass that to the child it works, so I'm confident the binding and child component logic is okay; I think it's just an issue with how/where I'm setting the value dynamically.

Here's the full parent component with some comments:

```
import { Component }                                                from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS }                                           from '@angular/http';
import { provide }                                                  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, Router, RouterUrlSerializer, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES }   from '@angular/router';
import { Location }                                                 from '@angular/common';
import { XHRBackend }                                               from '@angular/http';

import { ContentNode }                                              from './content-node';
import { ContentTreeComponent }                                     from './content-tree.component';
import { ContentDashboardComponent }                                from './content-dashboard.component';
import { ContentEditComponent }                                     from './content-edit.component';

import { ContentService }                                           from '../services/content.service';
import { InitService }                                              from '../services/init.service';
import { RouteNames }                                               from '../services/route-names.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-dashboard',
    template: `
        <div class="tree-panel-container">
            <div class="tree-panel-content">
                <content-tree [startNodeId]="startNodeIdContent" [currentNodeId]="currentNodeId"></content-tree>
            </div>
        </div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [
        ContentTreeComponent, 
        ContentDashboardComponent, 
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
    ],
    providers: [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS
    ]
})
@Routes([
    { path:'/',    component: ContentDashboardComponent },
    { path:'/:id', component: ContentEditComponent }
])
export class ContentComponent {

    _currentNodeId: number;

    constructor(private router:Router, private routeSerializer:RouterUrlSerializer, private location:Location) {
        router.changes.first().subscribe(() => {
            let urlTree = this.routeSerializer.parse(location.path());
            let urlSegment = urlTree.children(urlTree.children(urlTree.root)[0])[0];
            if(urlSegment != undefined){
                let id = urlSegment.segment;
                this._currentNodeId = id;
                console.log('_currentNodeId', this._currentNodeId); // This works - it logs the correct id from the route param
            }
        });
    }

    startNodeIdContent = InitService.startNodeIdContent;
    currentNodeId = this._currentNodeId; // This doesn't work - it just results in 'undefined' in the child component

    // The following line works; it passes 123 to the child component, so I know the binding and the child input is set up correctly:
    // currentNodeId = 123;
}
```

...and here's the child component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit }         from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouteSegment, RouteTree }  from '@angular/router';

import { ContentNode }                      from './content-node';
import { ContentService }                   from '../services/content.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'content-tree',
    directives: [ContentTreeComponent],
    template: `
        <ol class="tree">
            <li *ngFor="let contentNode of contentNodes" class="tree__branch" [ngClass]="{'tree__branch--has-children': contentNode.HasChildren}">
                <a *ngIf="contentNode.HasChildren" (click)="contentNode.toggle=!contentNode.toggle" class="tree__branch__toggle">
                    {{ !!contentNode.toggle ? '-' : '+' }}
                </a> 
                <a class="tree__branch__link" (click)="onSelect(contentNode)">{{ contentNode.Name }}</a>
                <content-tree *ngIf="contentNode.toggle" [startNodeId]="contentNode.Id"></content-tree>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <div class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</div>
        <p>{{test}}</p>
    `
})
export class ContentTreeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private _contentService: ContentService,
        private _router: Router,
        private _currSegment: RouteSegment
    ) { }

    errorMessage: string;

    @Input('startNodeId')
    private _startNodeId: number;

    @Input('currentNodeId')
    private _currentNodeId: number;

    contentNodes: ContentNode[];

    ngOnInit() { 
        this.getContentNodes();

        console.log('_startNodeId = ' + this._startNodeId);
        console.log('_currentNodeId = ' + this._currentNodeId);
    }

    onSelect(contentNode: ContentNode) {
        this._router.navigate([`./${contentNode.Id}`], this._currSegment);
    }

    getContentNodes() {
        this._contentService.getContentNodes(this._startNodeId)
            .subscribe(
                contentNodes => this.contentNodes = contentNodes,
                error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the Child component also

Comment: btw you should inject your InitService in the constructor , like constructor( InitService _initService , ......) and call the function like this 
startNodeIdContent = _initService.startNodeIdContent;

Comment: (Updated question to include child component)

Comment: Thanks pd farhad. Curious to why I should inject `InitService` into the constructor? I don't yet have a good enough understanding of constructors to know why this would be beneficial so would appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router adds components using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent`. For component added this way `@Input()` and `@Output()` isn't supported.

A common way to share data between components where inputs and outputs are not supported is a shared service. For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Good to know, thanks Günter. I'll proceed with a service.

Comment: thank you so much! been looking everywhere for this distinction. so important.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I tried to pass any value while I am routing to child component , so it seems it does not work because router adds ViewContainerRef.createComponent to those child components, so both @Input and @Output wont work, 
I made SharedService and initiate it inside the parent component and inject  this service where I need it .Hope it will help you too

Answer (score 0):

I created small library (which currently work only with angular 9, I can possibly add support for older versions, but with some additional code from your side)

```sh
npm install --save ngx-route-params-input
```

You can see it in action here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v8hdug?embed=1&file=src/app/user/user-routing.module.ts

It is working in the next way:

```js
// import component (you will also need to provide 
// NgxRouteParamsInputModule to your angular module imports)
import { NgxRouteParamsInputComponent } from "ngx-route-params-input";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ":userId",
    // Change YourComponent to NgxRouteParamsInputComponent:
    component: NgxRouteParamsInputComponent,
    data: {
      // Provide YourComponent in route data
      component: YourComponent,
      // Provide params you want to pass from URL to component
      routeParams: {
        userId: "userId"
      },
      // you can also provide query params
      queryParams: {
        content: "content"
      }
    }
  }
];
```

If you will have any issues or comment with this package, please feel free to add comments/ feature requests etc. at the GitHub (you can find it on npm site along with the documentation)